# removing thumbnail and links in woocommerce mini-cart, filter not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to remove product thumbnails from the WooCommerce StoreFront theme. I have every instance of them removed from the storefront generally, including the cart, but not the minicart in the main navigation/menubar.

The hooks are the same they are just not applying.

#### my filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_false' );
```

#### from `cart.php` line 68:

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

#### from `mini-cart.php` line 38:

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

This works for the cart where I am trying to remove it, but doesn't remove it from the minicart.

---

As a second example of a minicart problem, I am also removing the product link from the title. This works and it removes the link from the cart item (**as well as in the checkout when reviewing the order**), but still not from the minicart.

#### filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'mad_remove_cart_product_link', 1, 3 );
function mad_remove_cart_product_link( $product_link, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    return "0" . $product->get_title() . "0";
}
```

#### on line 83 of `cart.php`

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

#### on line 37 of `mini-cart.php`:

```
$product_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

*The visible `"0"` at each end of the product title in the filter is just for debugging. They obviously appear in the cart, the review area of the checkout, but not in the minicart*

Answer (score 1):

Just add another product to the cart and you will see your code working. WooCommerce uses sessionStorage, so as long the cart is not updated, it doesn't send any new ajax request, rather uses the value from sessionStorage :)

Comment: Now that you mention that I have seen something like that behaviour before. I don't think that's what's happening in this case. I've disabled a lot of plugins and reverted to the storefront theme, as well as added and removed items. For example, the mini-cart never get the `0` I mention in my second filter appearing in the product name, even after adding and removing several items.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your child theme functions.php

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_name_permalink', '__return_null' );`